# Problem with git - RPC failed curl 55 send failure

Tags: git, github

Can you help me troubleshoot what does this error mean?

```
Counting objects: 100% (160/160), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (154/154), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Broken pipeB/s
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (160/160), 34.64 MiB | 7.56 MiB/s, done.
Total 160 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I don't even know what to do. i updated the personal access token thought it could have been a problem but the token hasn't expired yet HELP.

Comment: Are you going through a proxy?

Comment: i don't think so, i'm working on a front-end code on localhost:5173